# Simple C code keeps crashing

Tags: c

So this is the code i did:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
char playerName;
int playerAge;

printf("What's your name, and your age?\nYour name: ");
scanf("%s\n", playerName);
printf("Your age: ");
scanf("%d\n", &playerAge);
printf("Okay %s, you are %d years old!", playerName, playerAge);

return 0;
}
```

And everytime i run it, after i input my name it crashes and i don't know how to fix it. These 3 things appear when it closes:

```
format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat]|

format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat]|

'playerName' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]|
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: Why do you attempt to store a string in a variable of type `char`?

Comment: Exactly what the compiler is telling you.

Comment: It's all in the error messages. You have `char` and not `char*` for `playerName`. You need to declare as `char * playerName`.

Comment: @melpomene My bad, misread the error message. Edited comment.

Comment: @Arc676 That would still leave `playerName` uninitialized.

Comment: @melpomene I am aware of that, but there was already an answer explaining how to solve that part. And I can't edit anymore. @OP Use `char playerName[size]` or `char * playerName = malloc(size)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf("%s\n", playerName);` is wrong because `%s` call for `char*` data but `playerName` here is type `char`.

You have to make `playerName` an array of characters and set max length of input to avoid buffer overflow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    char playerName[1024];
    int playerAge;

    printf("What's your name, and your age?\nYour name: ");
    scanf("%1023s\n", playerName); /* max length = # of elements - 1 for terminating null character */
    printf("Your age: ");
    scanf("%d\n", &playerAge);
    printf("Okay %s, you are %d years old!", playerName, playerAge);

    return 0;
}
```